# Wrap DOM element in another DOM element in PHP

Tags: php, html, dom

I originally asked a question along these lines using Regex but was recommended to use the PHP DOM library instead... which is superior, but I am still stuck.

Basically, I want to wrap the contents of an `<a>` in a `<span>` if it is not already wrapped in `<span>`.

```
<?php
$input = <<<EOT
<html><head></head>
<body bgcolor="#393a36">
    <a href="#"><span style="color:#ffffff;">Link 1</span></a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#"><img src="mypic.gif" />Image Link</a>
    <a href="#"><u>Underlined Link</u></a>
</body>
</html>
EOT;


$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($input);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $spancount = $tag->getElementsByTagName("span")->length;
    if($spancount == 0){
        $content = nodeContent($tag);
        $element = $doc->createElement('span');
        $element->setAttribute('style','color:#ffffff;');
        $frag = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
        $frag->appendXML($content);
        $element->appendChild($frag);   
        $tag->nodeValue = ""; //clear node
        $tag->appendChild($element);
    }
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();

function nodeContent($n, $outer=false) { 
    $d = new DOMDocument('1.0'); 
    $d->formatOutput = true;
    $b = $d->importNode($n->cloneNode(true),true); 
    $d->appendChild($b);
    $h = $d->saveHTML(); 
    // remove outter tags 
    if (!$outer) $h = substr($h,strpos($h,'>')+1,-(strlen($n->nodeName)+4)); 
    return $h; 
}
```

It provides this output:

> PHP Warning:  DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Premature end of data in tag img line 1 in /private/var/folders/78/78vHGigZHcuFeXB1KKJSb++++TI/-Tmp-/untitled_3xd..php on line 24
>   PHP Warning:  DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML(): Image Link in /private/var/folders/78/78vHGigZHcuFeXB1KKJSb++++TI/-Tmp-/untitled_3xd..php on line 24
>   PHP Warning:  DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML():                                ^ in /private/var/folders/78/78vHGigZHcuFeXB1KKJSb++++TI/-Tmp-/untitled_3xd..php on line 24
>   PHP Warning:  DOMNode::appendChild(): Document Fragment is empty in /private/var/folders/78/78vHGigZHcuFeXB1KKJSb++++TI/-Tmp-/untitled_3xd..php on line 25

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>  
<head></head>  
<body bgcolor="#393a36">  
    <a href="#"><span style="color:#ffffff;">Link 1</span></a>  
    <a href="#"><span style="color:#ffffff;">Link 2</span></a>  
    <a href="#"><span style="color:#ffffff;"></span></a>  
    <a href="#"><span style="color:#ffffff;"><u>Underlined Link</u></span></a>  
</body>  
</html>
```

This mostly works, except that it is really picky, and as you can see it dies if here is an `img` (or similar) tag inside the `a href`.

What is the best way to make this work. I've been banging my head against for an embarrassing long time now.

**EDIT**

Based on feedback below, here is the revised code and output.  Note that the text preceding the `img` tag isn't being wrapped for some reason.  Any Ideas?

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($input);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $spancount = $tag->getElementsByTagName("span")->length;
    if($spancount == 0){
    $element = $doc->createElement('span');
    $element->setAttribute('style','color:#ffffff;');
    foreach ($tag->childNodes as $child) {
        $tag->removeChild($child);
        $element->appendChild($child);
    }
    $tag->appendChild($element);

    }
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head></head>
<body bgcolor="#393a36">
    <a href="#"><span style="color:#ffffff;">Link 1</span></a>
    <a href="#"><span style="color:#ffffff;">Link 2</span></a>
    <a href="#">Image Link<span style="color:#ffffff;"><img src="mypic.gif"></span></a>
    <a href="#"><span style="color:#ffffff;"><u>Underlined Link</u></span></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why bother with re-creating the node?  Why not just replace the node? (If I understand what you're trying to do)...

```
if($spancount == 0){
    $element = $doc->createElement('span');
    $element->setAttribute('style','color:#ffffff;');
    $tag->parentNode->replaceChild($element, $tag);
    $element->apendChild($tag);
}
```

**Edit** Whoops, it looks like you're trying to wrap everything under `$tag` in the span...  Try this instead:

```
if($spancount == 0){
    $element = $doc->createElement('span');
    $element->setAttribute('style','color:#ffffff;');
    foreach ($tag->childNodes as $child) {
        $tag->removeChild($child);
        $element->appendChild($child);
    }
    $tag->appendChild($child);
}
```

**Edit2** Based on your results, it looks like that foreach is not completing because of the node removal...  Try replacing the foreach with this:

```
while ($tag->childNodes->length > 0) {
    $child = $tag->childNodes->item(0);
    $tag->removeChild($child);
    $element->appendChild($child);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works almost great.  See the Edited OP above.   In the case of the link with the `<img />` tag in it, the text is not getting wrapped in the new `<span>` just the `<img />`.

Answer (score 2):

This is great information, and sorry to come so late into the party, but there's one error for me... at the end:

```
$tag->appendChild($child);
```

should be

```
$tag->appendChild($element);
```

That's the only way I could get this to work.