# Regex PHP: find text after certain tag

Tags: php, regex

I've got entries in the database like that:

```
<div>
   <a href="path/img.jpg">
     <img src="path/img.jpg"/>
   </a> 
   Photograph: Name of Photographer
</div>
```

Want I want to reach is, making a p-Tag around the imagedescription

To grab the text, i've got the regex like that:

```
$regex_pattern = "/.jpg\"\/><\/a>(.*)<\/div>/";
$replace = ".jpg\"/></a><p class=\"img-caption\">$1</p></div>/";
$content = preg_replace($regex_pattern, $replace, $content);
```

but i get an empty p-tag after my image-description. What am i doing wrong

Comment: "some error" is horribly unspecific.WHAT error do you get? Errormessage? Anything?

Comment: I can't stress this enough not to use regex for HTML parsing. Please use DOMDocument instead.

Comment: but how to get a text that's not in a tag? how to get the image-description with DOMDocument and wrap it with less steps than with regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included possible whitespaces or newlines, change your pattern to this:

```
$regex_pattern = "/.jpg\"\/>\s*<\/a>\s*(.*)\s*<\/div>/";
```

Check it here:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d74f8c65c3cef80fe88721269e2c97004e0b9a68

Comment: thanks for your propose but it's still the same, empty p-tag after imagedescription

Comment: It works for me, look at the sandbox, I included the link.

Comment: there was one more whitespace: $regex_pattern = "/.jpg\"\s*\/>\s*<\/a>\s*(.*)\s*<\/div>/"; Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I can't stress this enough not to use regex for HTML parsing. Instead, it's easier and safer using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). This is just one of several ways to accomplish your goal. The idea is to parse the HTML, find the last text node, then wrap it in `<p>` tags.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

// Load the HTML without saving the wrapper info
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$textNodes = $xp->query('//div/text()');
$lastTextNode = $textNodes->item($textNodes->length - 1);

$element = $dom->createElement('p');
$element->nodeValue = $lastTextNode->nodeValue;
$lastTextNode->parentNode->replaceChild($element, $lastTextNode);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

**Output:**

```
<div>
   <a href="path/img.jpg">
     <img src="path/img.jpg">
   </a><p> 
   Photograph: Name of Photographer
</p></div>
```

**Demo:** [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/DUAVNk)

---

More reading: [Wrap DOM element in another DOM element in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524431/wrap-dom-element-in-another-dom-element-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for your time and your explanation! I also like your way, probably less complicated than the regex, but ... you have to admit, it's not shorter.

Comment: Just wait until the HTML gets longer, more complicated, and/or malformed... DOMDocument can handle all those cases. Tuck this method under your hat for future projects. ;)