# Wrap table tag around div tag

Tags: wordpress

I tried to use this snippet of code to wrap a div tag around each table tag within post content, but I don't know why it doesn't work:

```
function tekst_wrapper($content) {
  return preg_replace_callback('~<table.*</table>~i', function($match) {
    return '<div>' . $match[0] . '</div>';
  }, $content);
}

add_filter('the_content', 'tekst_wrapper');
```

Comment: This is a good question and a good answer. Would you mind please updating the title of your post to "Wrap div tags around table element" for clarity? Right now the title is backwards from your actual question. Thanks btw, this thread helped me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try with question mark after wildcard ( zero or more spaces ) and "s" flag after "i" flag. 
First change should help your regular expression function to differentiate between variations of table tag with or without spaces and attributes. 
Second should include newlines in regex search:

```
~<table.*?</table>~is
```

and full code would be

```
function tekst_wrapper($content) {
  return preg_replace_callback('~<table.*?</table>~is', function($match) {
    return '<div>' . $match[0] . '</div>';
  }, $content);
}

add_filter('the_content', 'tekst_wrapper');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, niklaz. It worked like a charm. Actually I had found that code form here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304589/wrap-div-around-p-tag-using-php-wordpress  I just wonder why the original code worked with p tag but doesn't work with table tag?

Comment: Hi, glad that it helped. I think that it worked because probably all paragraph tag pairs were in same line set "<p>...</p>" and there was no need for "s" flag.