# RegEx find all anchor tags, including ones with images

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace-callback

I am trying to find all `<a>` tags and add a div around them. How do you change the RegEx to match `<a><img></a>` as well as `<a>text</a>`, or any tags within the `<a>` tag. I have:

```
<php

    $a_pattern = '@<a\s*.*>.*(<.*>)?.*</a>@i';
    $out = preg_replace_callback($a_pattern,"match_callback",$html);
    function match_callback($matches)
    {
         var_dump($matches);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Just FYI: this task is best done with an HTML parser.

Comment: Like simple HTML DOM Parser? I will have to see how to modify the HTML as I have only ever extracted using that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, anyone have info on replacing <a>...</a> with <div><a>...</a></div> using HTML parser?

Comment: See [*Wrap DOM element in another DOM element in PHP*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524431/wrap-dom-element-in-another-dom-element-in-php).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks but that shows how to replace the innerHTML with something, I want to wrap the <a> with a <div> so replace <a>...</a> with <div><a>...</a></div>

Comment: The point is to get the as you need and create divs from the parent document, and then add the a tag as a child to it and then replace the a with the new div. I can't help more as I'm on a mobile now.

Comment: Tony the pony, he comes... http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/236345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with a built-in PHP DOM parser (using with a some fake HTML, but you will get the idea):

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML('<body>
     <a href="somewere"><img src="www.foo.com/example.gif" class="foo" alt="..."><br></a>
     <a href="somewere again"><img src="www.bar.com/1.jpg" class="bar" alt="..."></a>
     <a href="somewere again and back">Text</a>
     </body>
', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a_node) {
   $div = $a_node->ownerDocument->createElement('div');
   $node = $a_node->parentNode->insertBefore($div, $a_node);
   $node->appendChild($a_node);
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Output of the [sample demo](http://ideone.com/Ovg7bX):

```
<body>
<div><a href="somewere"><img src="www.foo.com/example.gif" class="foo" alt="..."><br></a></div>
<div><a href="somewere%20again"><img src="www.bar.com/1.jpg" class="bar" alt="..."></a></div>
<div><a href="somewere%20again%20and%20back">Text</a></div>
</body>
```

You can also add attributes with the help of:

```
$node->setAttribute('class', 'title');
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I ended up just doing it in jQuery.

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 processATags();
});
function processATags() {
 $('a').each(function() {
  $(this).append('<div></div>');
 }); 
}
</script>