# Using DomDocument to involve a element with another element?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I have tree divs inside a father div called `results_all` as you can see below:

```
<div id="results_all">

<div class="result_information">
</div>

<div class="result_information">
</div>

<div class="result_information">
</div>

</div>
```

all I want to do is involve all divs whose class is called `result_information`, with the following code `<tr><th>`.

so that the final results to be:

```
<tr><th>
<div class="result_information">
</div>
</th></tr>

<tr><th>
<div class="result_information">
</div>
</th></tr>

<tr><th>
<div class="result_information">
</div>
</th></tr>
```

How I can do this kind of thing using DomDocument with PHP?

Comment: PHP doesn't interact with the DOM.  Are you doing this client-side with javascript, or while rendering the HTML server-side with PHP?

Comment: I have that HTML inside a variable in PHP, I used the class domdocument before to doing other things. But this kind of thing I don't know how to solve...

Comment: basically a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524431/wrap-dom-element-in-another-dom-element-in-php

Answer (score 0):

This will match the class using DOMXPath, it's then just a case of outputting the matched content with the appropriate tags when you loop over the results.

```
$html = '<div id="results_all">

<div class="result_information">
test3
</div>

<div class="result_information">
test2
</div>

<div class="result_information">
test
</div>

</div>
';

$classname = 'result_information';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$results = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");


for($i = 0; $i < $results->length; $i++ ){
  print '<tr><th><div class="result_information">' . $results->item($i)->nodeValue . '</div></tr></th>';
}
```